# Give a size to a vector in a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

If this is working,

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(31); // vector with size 31
}
```

why isn't this working in this class

```
class Mlass
{
  private:
    std::vector<int> vec(31);
}
```

Comment: Add `Mlass() : vec(31) {}` and replace `std::vector<int> vec(31);` with `std::vector<int>;`

Comment: Try `std::vector<int> vec{31};` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/qje36qvMe

Comment: Try `std::vector<int> vec = std::vector(31);` [https://ideone.com/7BIn4f](https://ideone.com/7BIn4f)

Comment: @RichardCritten: It would not be the same content...

Comment: @RichardCritten this inserts only one element - `31` - into the vector, see here https://godbolt.org/z/5WaEdba9Y

Comment: Please make a new question, there's a button for that on the top-right of the page. Changing the post to ask a totally different thing is not allowed.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I can't ask questions already 5 monts what can i do?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Please read here, it contains all the information known about question bans: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/7328782